# How to apply last-child only for first nested li?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following ul list:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li></li>
<ul>
```

How can I apply CSS style to last `li` of parent `class="list"`, not for nested `ul` inside `ul`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `last-of-type` and `>`

```css
.list > li:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>a
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

As you mention that you want last element of `li`'s parent you use `last-of-type` selector, which matches every element that is the last child of a particular type, of its parent.

Second, to only match the outer most `li` and not nested one's, you use the child selecor `>` which in this case says: *match the last of type which is an immediate child of an element having a class named `.list`*

You also want to have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).

Comment: You've missed a really important part in the explanation ... the role the child selector play

Comment: Did not get you @LGSon, feel free to post your answer with detail too as i will always love to learn :)

Comment: Updated/Upvoted yours as you had it with a minor change :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38ksdpw3/22/)**

**css**

```
ul.main > li > ul> li:first-child > a {
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to mention but op wanted to have css for last li of parent.

Answer (score 1):

**DIRECT CHILD SELECTOR (CSS3):**

```css
ul.list >li:last-of-type{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li>Parent First Child
        <ul>
            <li>Child</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>Parent Another Child</li>
     <li>Parent Last Child</li>
<ul>
```

> Note : `>` is used for selecting direct child of `ul.list`

Here is the details about [CSS Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: What is the difference between your example and mine?

Comment: What happen if `<div class='list'></div>`? I just specified the selector. @Leothelion

Comment: yes in that case still it will be same as m pointing out the class but not div.

Comment: I didn't copied or modified your answer. Do you want me to delete my answer? @Leothelion